# How to conduct the derivation/proof from the general version of chain rule to the Conditional Independent version?

Tags: probability

I am aware of the general [chain rule for random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)#More_than_two_random_variables)

${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\mathrm {P} (X_{4},X_{3},X_{2},X_{1})&=\mathrm {P} (X_{4}\mid X_{3},X_{2},X_{1})\cdot \mathrm {P} (X_{3},X_{2},X_{1})\\&=\mathrm {P} (X_{4}\mid X_{3},X_{2},X_{1})\cdot \mathrm {P} (X_{3}\mid X_{2},X_{1})\cdot \mathrm {P} (X_{2},X_{1})\\&=\mathrm {P} (X_{4}\mid X_{3},X_{2},X_{1})\cdot \mathrm {P} (X_{3}\mid X_{2},X_{1})\cdot \mathrm {P} (X_{2}\mid X_{1})\cdot \mathrm {P} (X_{1})\end{aligned}}}$

this [CMU Machine Learning Course](https://youtu.be/tpmdcJYnAyQ?t=2080) gives this form, with Conditional Independence assumption

[image]

How to conduct the derivation/proof from the general version to the Conditional Independent version pointed out by red rectangle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$P(X_1, X_2, Y)=P(X_1|X_2, Y)P(X_2|Y)P(Y)$$

Now, divide both sides by $P(Y)$,

That would give you,

$$P(X_1, X_2|Y)=P(X_1|X_2,Y)P(X_2|Y)$$